# laravel 8 search / filter on datatble server side processing

Tags: laravel

I am applying a custom search and custom filter on the data table using laravel 8. I am applying a department filter to the data table. MY controller code is here.  I am adding search input box condition Now I want to add filter department condition in my controller. How can I add this? If i am adding `if ($request->has('department')) {}` it throws me an error.

My blade.php file

```
<div class="department">
    <select class="form-control" id="Department" name="Department" aria-label="Default select example">
        <option value="" selected>Select Department</option>
        <option value="Testing">Testing</option>
        <option value="HR">HR</option>
        <option value="Admin Department">Admin Department</option>
        <option value="Research and Development">Research and Development</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-9 table-responsive mt-5">
    <table class="table table-bordered user_datatable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Sr.No.</th>
                <th>Employee_Code</th>
                <th>Employee_Name</th>
                <th>Employee_Age</th>
                <th>Employee_Contact_No</th>
                <th>Department</th>
                <th>Salary_Grade</th>
                <th>Employee_Email</th>
                <th width="100px">Employee_Photo</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) 
    {  

        $data = Employee::select('id','Employee_Code','Employee_Name','Employee_Age','Employee_Contact_No','Department','Salary_Grade','Employee_Email','Employee_Photo')->get();
        return Datatables::of($data)
        ->filter(function ($instance) use ($request) {
            if ($request->has('search')) {
                $instance->collection = $instance->collection->filter(function ($row) use ($request) 
                {
                    return Str::contains($row['id'], $request->get('search')) or 
                           Str::contains($row['Employee_Code'], $request->get('search')) or
                           Str::contains($row['Employee_Age'], $request->get('search')) or
                           Str::contains($row['Employee_Contact_No'], $request->get('search')) or
                           Str::contains($row['Department'], $request->get('search')) or
                           Str::contains($row['Salary_Grade'], $request->get('search')) or
                           Str::contains($row['Employee_Email'], $request->get('search'))
                            ? true : false;
                  
                });
            }

        })
        ->addColumn('Employee_Photo', function($row){
            $btn = '<img src="employee_images/'.$row->Employee_Photo.' " height="60" width="100"/>';
            return $btn;
        })
        ->rawColumns(['Employee_Photo'])
        ->make(true);
    }

}
```

jquery:

```
  $(function () {
       var search=$('input[type="search"]').val();
       var department=$(this).val();
       var table = $('.user_datatable').DataTable({
           destroy: true,
           processing: true,
           caseInsensitive: true,
           serverSide: true,
           paginationType: "full_numbers",
           lengthMenu: [[5, 10, 15, 20], [5, 10, 15, 20]],
           ajax: {
             url:'/show_result',
             data:{search:search,department:department}
          },
           columns: [
               {data: 'id'},
               {data: 'Employee_Code'},
               {data: 'Employee_Name'},
               {data: 'Employee_Age'},
               {data: 'Employee_Contact_No'},
               {data: 'Department'},
               {data: 'Salary_Grade'},
               {data: 'Employee_Email'},
               {data: 'Employee_Photo', orderable: false, searchable: false},
           ]
       });
     });
```

Comment: have you tried to add with `else if ($request->has('department')) {}` condition?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add `else if () { ... }` condition?

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) 
    {  

        $data = Employee::select('id','Employee_Code','Employee_Name','Employee_Age','Employee_Contact_No','Department','Salary_Grade','Employee_Email','Employee_Photo')->get();
        return Datatables::of($data)
        ->filter(function ($instance) use ($request) {
            if ($request->has('search')) {
                $instance->collection = $instance->collection->filter(function ($row) use ($request) 
                {
                    return Str::contains($row['id'], $request->get('search')) or 
                           Str::contains($row['Employee_Code'], $request->get('search')) or
                           Str::contains($row['Employee_Age'], $request->get('search')) or
                           Str::contains($row['Employee_Contact_No'], $request->get('search')) or
                           Str::contains($row['Department'], $request->get('search')) or
                           Str::contains($row['Salary_Grade'], $request->get('search')) or
                           Str::contains($row['Employee_Email'], $request->get('search'))
                            ? true : false;
                  
                });
            } elseif ($request->has('department')) {
                // your condition
            }

        })
        ->addColumn('Employee_Photo', function($row){
            $btn = '<img src="employee_images/'.$row->Employee_Photo.' " height="60" width="100"/>';
            return $btn;
        })
        ->rawColumns(['Employee_Photo'])
        ->make(true);
    }

}
```